# Partially renaming multiple Excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I need help regarding renaming of excel sheets partially . 
I have about 40 of these which needs partial renaming every month .

For eg :

```
     2017_06 Jun QFR Planning File,

     2017_06 Jun QFR Analytics File,

     2017_06 Jun QFR Customer Service File
```

would need to be renamed to

```
     2017_07 Jul QCR Planning File

     2017_07 Jul QCR Analytics File  

     2017_07 Jul QCR Customer Service File .
```

Please help me in automating this. I tried looking online but every VBA code seems to change the name entirely . I want the files to have their respective file name and be successful in partially renaming them.

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What happened when you tried it?  Please include the code you used, and a description of the problems you had, or else we won't be "helping" you, we will just have to do all the work ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1:** Use `Name As` statement

You can use `Name As` method like this:

```
'/* Syntax: Name [oldfilename] As [newfilename] */
'/* where oldfilename and newfilename are full file paths */
Name "C:\Test\2017_06 Jun QFR Planning.xlsx" As "C:\Test\2017_06 Jun QCR Planning.xlsx"
```

If you have a lot of files, then you can incorporate a loop.

```
Dim xlFile As Variant
Dim nFile As String

xlFile = Dir("C:\Test\*.xls*") '/* Folder that contains the files */

Do While xlFile <> "" '/* check if anything is returned */
    If InStr(xlFile, "QFR") <> 0 Then '/* check if there is 'QFR' in the filename
        nFile = VBA.Replace(xlFile, "QFR", "QCR") '/* replace if there is */
        Name xlFile As nFile '/* rename the file */
    End If
    xlFile = Dir '/* Test for more */
Loop
```